# python and pandas plot between two dates index value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe

```
DATE;NORD
2017-01-01 00:00:00;51.22
2017-01-01 01:00:00;53.0
2017-01-01 02:00:00;52.0
2017-01-01 03:00:00;51.0
2017-01-01 04:00:00;47.27
2017-01-01 05:00:00;45.49
2017-01-01 06:00:00;45.69
2017-01-01 07:00:00;48.07
...
```

I read it as:

```
DF = pd.read_csv(fname, sep=';',index_col=0, header = 0)
```

I would like to plot in the matplolib framework it but selecting between two dates and at the same time I would like to have as x-ticks the date.

I usually use to plot all the dataframe and it is quite easy to get what I want:

```
ax.plot(DATAF.index.values,DATAF['NORD'].values)
```

However, I have a problem when I want to plot only between two selected date. In the following an example:

```
sp = '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
ep = '2017-01-02 00:00:00'

ax.plot(DF.index.values[sp:ep],DF.loc[sp:ep,:].values)
```

It does not work. It seems to not have a problem with:

```
DF.loc[sp:ep,:].values)
```

but with

```
DF.index.values[sp:ep]
```

thanks for any kind of helps or suggestions.

Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are also there. You can filter then use the [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) function:

```
df.loc[sp:ep].plot(y='NORD')
```

Or if you prefer using matplotlib directly:

```
df_plot = df.loc[sp:ep]
ax.plot(df_plot.index, df_plot['NORD'])
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the results unreadable. I have tried with #ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter(r'\textbf{%Y-%m-%d}'))
But it seems not to work.

Comment: I get it. I have to convert the index in date.  DF.index = pd.to_datetime(DF.index)